# Accessing the find box from a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to access the find box from a chrome extension? I want to manipulate the text in the find box when the user hits ctrl+f

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to directly access the Find Dialog when it is called/invoked. These are based on the solutions on the related question - [Chrome Extension: How can I show the find bar and supply text for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13714935/5995040) and [chrome extension: how to bind/hook to the browser's “search invoked” event?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14533581/5995040)

However, the workaround for this is use the Command API or [window.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/find).

#### Command API

You can try [**`chrome.commands`**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands), use the commands API to add keyboard shortcuts that trigger actions in your extension, for example, an action to open the browser action or send a command to the extension.

Hope this helps.